# Ubuntu 18 Workspace Thumbnails

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, workspaces, workspace-switcher, productivity

Is there any Gnome extension that does the same as the "Taskbar Pager" plugin for "Dexpot" on Windows.

I want to see what windows I am working with on every workspace.

The plugin I am giving as an example allows you to move windows between workspaces with drag and drop.

You can see Windows' taskbar in the picture. On the right side of the taskbar, you can see in a red rectangle with representations of the 4 workspaces.

I would like to see all my workspaces in Ubuntu's launcher. It would be nice too if I can move windows between workspaces using drag & drop just as it happens with Dexpot's "Taskbar Pager" on Windows.

Is there any extension for Gnome that can do this?

[image]